# Mulesoft flow timeout

Tags: xml, mule

I am designing an api using Mulesoft and I would like to have it return a generic response when it takes more than 10 seconds to respond. Currently I am accomplishing this by using an HTTP connector to call another flow within the api.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<flow name="Incomming-Flow">
    <!-- get request -->
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/validationWithTimeout" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
        <!-- Set payload to generic response when http call times out -->
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
<flow name="Processing-Flow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/validationWithTimeout" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <!-- 
        processing components go here
     -->
</flow>
```

Is there a better way of stopping a flow and returning a generic response when it has taken too long?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the above configuration,the only missing point is timeout variable and usage of it,please define timeout for 10 seconds for response and when ever it is timeout needs to throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

One way - Capture within exception handling itself and set the status required, in set payload set whatever the generic response required. Sample is as below Or you can also use Mapping-exception Strategy to capture based on status code.

```
<flow name="Incomming-Flow">
   <!-- get request -->
   <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/validationWithTimeout" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" when="java.net.ConnectException">
     <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="#[403]" doc:name="Property"/>
     <set-payload value="{&quot;success&quot;:false,&quot;errors&quot;:[{&quot;code&quot;:&quot;50001&quot;,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;Internal Server Error&quot;,&quot;details&quot;:&quot;An internal system error has occurred, please contact the support team.&quot;}]}" doc:name="Set Payload" mimeType="application/json"/>
  </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question.  Im not worried about catching the exception.  I want to be able to throw an exception if the flow takes more than 10 seconds.  I don't want to have to use an http connector inside my api to call itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure the defaultResponseTimeout in the Global Settings Configuration. Put the following inside your `<mule>` element.
`<configuration defaultResponseTimeout="10000"></configuration>`
But note that this will apply to all flows. You can then configure the exception in your exception handler.

[Global Configuration Settings](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/about-mule-configuration#global-configuration-settings)

[Global Configuration Attributes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/global-settings-configuration-reference#attributes-of-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

First Configure **Http** inside a **poll** connector and then set the polling frequency as 1sec for your requirement and use for each then in the counter variable inside the **foreach** it will be updated for each and every second, in the **setpayload** check whether the counter is equals to 10 if it is equals to 10 send your required response.

Answer (score 0):

Set your timeout to 10 seconds in Http connector.
In the exception strategy,please configure the timeout exception flow with the generic payload you want to return for the API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

a. Globally for a given application

Add the global element configuration in the application and set the attribute defaultResponseTimeout:

```
<configuration defaultResponseTimeout="10000" />
```

b. Specifically for a flow

Add the attached TimeoutMessageProcessor to your application and place it before the outbound endpoint:

```
<custom-processor class="com.mule.support.TimeoutMessageProcessor">
    <spring:property name="timeout" value="10000" />
</custom-processor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Our team implemented a spring boot connector and made configurations there to handle this issue. No problems since.

Answer (score -1):

As per your configuration, flow will be trying to hit the above url. Please find below a sample HTTP request configuration with response time outs (you can avoid the TLS part, if you are using only HTTP, and not HTTPS):

```
<configuration defaultTransactionTimeout="300000" defaultResponseTimeout="300000" doc:name="Configuration">
 <default-threading-profile poolExhaustedAction="RUN"/>
```

Hope help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using polling to check it for every second and set a variable and as soon as the count reaches 10 i.e 10 seconds you can print the error message or direct to the required exception flow.

Answer (score -1):

If this is specific to the API/flow , it is appropriate to handle in exception strategy and build a Dataweave to map the generic response.

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether you are able to access the rest service by other means, other than connecting through mule flows. Do you really have the service running, which takes below url format and exposed as a GET service:
 http://1.1.1.1:80/TEST_OUTBOUND

Answer (score -1):

Set your timeout to 10 seconds in Http connector. In the exception strategy, please configure the timeout exception flow with the generic payload you want to return to the API.